# How to make the 'int' to 'string' with special format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, int

```
    int score=8;
    scoreLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%5d",score];
```

I want to make the scoreLabe show the text '00008',but when the line code was executing,the result is '8',can any one tell me how to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05d", score]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *numStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%05d", yourNum];
```

Comment: Why it is down voted ? I know it was duplicate of above answer, but I submitted it before that was posted !

Comment: sorry , I don't know, it's not me, but thank you for your answer.

Comment: @MSK: Check out your answer's and Behlul's answer time. You will understand why someone down voted you.

Comment: @ParthBhatt Yes probably. I started early but submitted late ( doing other stuff in parallel) and not realized it was already answered. It was my first or second attempt to answer here.